# Добавить условия запроса к БД yii2

Tags: yii2

Делаю поиск, нужно в зависимости от наличия get параметров добавлять условие к выборке из БД. Как можно сделать что-то подобное?

```
public function actionSearch()
{
    $result = Orders::find()
        ->joinWith('client')
        ->one();

    $id =Yii::$app->request->get('id');
    if ($id != null)
    {
        $result = $result->where(['client.id' => $id]) ;
    }

    return $this->render('search', [
        'result' => $result
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать форму, в которой вы сможете провалидировать данные и построить запрос. Форма вам вернет ActiveRecord

```
class OrderForm extends yii\base\Model
{
    public $clientId;
    public $sum;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['clientId', ExistValidator::className(), 'targetClass' => 'Client', 'targetAttribute' => 'id'],
            ['sum', 'integer'],
        ];
    }

    public function search() {
        $query = Orders::find()->joinWith('client');
            $query->andFilterWhere([
                'client.id' => $this->id,
                'sum' => $this->sum,
            ]);
        return $query;
    }
}
```

В контроллере остается только работа с формой

```
public function actionSearch()
{
    $form = new OrderForm();
    $form->load(\Yii::$app->request->getQueryParams(), '');
    return $this->render('search', [
        'result' => $form->search()->one()
    ]);
}
```

Еще плюс такого подхода вы разделяете логику контроллера и модели, так же тесты писать проще.

Answer (score 2):

У Вас ошибка была в том, что вы использовали ->where() для массива $result, хотя этот метод используется только объектом ActiveRecord для построения запроса

Как вариант вот так

```
public function actionSearch()
{

    $where = [];
    // необязательно делать это циклом, но мало ли у вас будет 10 параметров get.
    foreach (Yii::$app->request->getQueryParams as $k => $get) {
       if (!empty($get) && $k !== 'r')
           $where = array_merge($where, ['client.'.$k => $get]); // тут можно добавлять отдельные условия проверяя $k если требуется
    }
    $result = Orders::find()
        ->joinWith('client')
        ->where(count($where) > 0 ? $where : '1')
        ->one();

    return $this->render('search', [
        'result' => $result
    ]);
}
```